# Classification of isometries of hyperbolic 3-space

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups, hyperbolic-geometry

Denote the upper half space by $\mathcal{H}_{3}=\Bbb{C}\times (0,\infty)$. A point $P \in \mathcal{H}_{3}$ is given as, $P=(z, t)=(x, y, t)=z+t j$ where $z=x+i y$ and $j=(0,0,1) .$ The group $P S L_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ has a natural action on $\mathcal{H}_{3} .$ Let $M=\left(\begin{array}{c}\alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta\end{array}\right)$
and $P=z+t j$ a point in $\mathcal{H}_{3}$. Then, $P S L_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ acts on $\mathcal{H}_{3}$ via linear fractional transformation as follows
$$
M \times P \rightarrow \frac{\alpha P+\beta}{\gamma P+\delta}
$$
More explicitly we have $M(z+t j)=z^{*}+t^{*} j \in \mathcal{H}_{3}$ where
$$
\begin{array}{l}
z^{*}=\frac{(\alpha z+\beta)(\bar{\gamma} \bar{z}+\bar{\delta})+\alpha \bar{\gamma} t^{2}}{|\gamma z+\delta|^{2}+|\gamma|^{2} t^{2}} \\
t^{*}=\frac{t}{|\gamma z+\delta|^{2}+|\gamma|^{2} t^{2}}
\end{array}
$$

I want to prove the following three statements: Let $M\in PSL_2(\Bbb{C})$.

- $M$ is  it has a fixed point in $\mathcal{H}_{3}$ $\Longleftrightarrow \operatorname{Tr}(M) \in(-2,2)$
- $M$ has no fixed point in $\mathcal{H}_{3}$ and a single fixed point on $\partial \mathcal{H}_3, \Longleftrightarrow \operatorname{Tr}(M)=\pm 2,$
- $M$ has no fixed point in $\mathcal{H}_3$ and exactly 2 fixed points on $\partial \mathcal{H}_3$. $\Longleftrightarrow \operatorname{Tr}(M) \notin[-2,2]$ (and hyperbolic $\Longleftrightarrow \operatorname{Tr}(M) \in \mathbb{R} \backslash[-2,2])$.

My attempt:
If $M$ fixes a point $P$ then we have the following equations

$$\frac{(\alpha z+\beta)(\bar{\gamma} \bar{z}+\bar{\delta})+\alpha \bar{\gamma} t^{2}}{|\gamma z+\delta|^{2}+|\gamma|^{2} t^{2}}=z$$ and $$\frac{t}{|\gamma z+\delta|^{2}+|\gamma|^{2} t^{2}}=t$$

So this gives $|\gamma z+\delta|^{2}+|\gamma|^{2} t^{2}=1$ and $(\alpha z+\beta)(\bar{\gamma} \bar{z}+\bar{\delta})+\alpha \bar{\gamma} t^{2}=z$. After these two equations, I am not able to solve $z$ and $t$. I want to see relations between the trace and fixed points. I would be very glad if someone is able to relate the trace of $M$ to the fixed points of $M$ from my equations. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a relevant discussion here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Classification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $M\in\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ be distinct from $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. If $M$ has distinct eigenvalues, then it is conjugate within $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ to a diagonal matrix. If $M$ has equal eigenvalues, then it is conjugate within $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ to $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

The three statements in the original post are invariant under conjugation, so it suffices to verify them for diagonal matrices and $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Which is straightforward.

Comment: I have some confusions. If I choose $M=\left(\begin{array}{c}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$, then $\alpha=1, \beta=1, \gamma=0$ and $\delta=1$. In this case, I find $z+1=z$ by using the definition of the action. So I could not see any fixed point neither in the boundary nor $\mathcal{H}_3$.

Comment: @ersin: The point $\infty$ is the unique fixed point of $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, and it is usually regarded as a boundary point. In fact $\mathrm{PSL_2(\mathbb{C})}$ acts transitively on $\mathcal{H}_3\cup\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$, where $\mathbb{C}$ is the usual boundary of $\mathcal{H}_3$. In short, the point $\infty$ must be included. If you look at the ball model of hyperbolic-space, then naturally the boundary is the Riemann sphere, that is, $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$.

Comment: @ersin. Continued from previous remark: You can find these facts in many textbooks and lecture notes, e.g. googling for "PSL(2,C) acting on hyperbolic space" gives as the first hit http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~sb/LTCCcourse/Holodyn2013notes_week3.pdf which says the same thing.